# Python - how to let users run script with libraries

Tags: python, git, github, pyinstaller

I plan on sharing a Python program on GitHub.

However it uses additional libraries like http, Selenium, BeautifulSoup and the Google Calendar API.

How do I *include* these libraries in the directory I push to GitHub, so that all users have to do is run `python script.py`, instead of having to install the libraries?

I thought of generating an executable with pyinstaller but that didn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You use a pip [requirements.txt file](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) for this.

If you have done your work inside of a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) then run on your command line/terminal:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then commit and push the file to your github repository.

If you have not done your script within a virtual environment then run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And edit the file so you only have the modules you require.

I'd recommend always use a virtual environment for this since it makes your application easy to share. In [django framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/) employing virtualenv's is very common.

Your collaborators can install your dependencies using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After cloning your github repo.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you don't need to embed your dependencies in your project (not practical! specially when they are many). Instead you may include `requirements.txt` inside your project to list the modules (and version number) that are required by your application. Then when a user need to use your script, they can run something like this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

read more about requirements files here:

https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html#requirements-files